# Shortcode does not expand in Facebook like

Tags: plugins, facebook, shortcode

I am using [Facebook Like Button](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-like-button/) plugin on pages that just contains a shortcode. When I Like the page and post to Facebook, it shows the shortcode without expanding it. I want to show the expanded contents in Facebook activity stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, it sounds like the content is being sent without using [do_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode), find the portion of the plugin that posts to facebook for you and ensure shortcodes are being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different plugin that does handle that sort of thing properly: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/

It's a bit more involved of a setup, but it handles all the metadata correctly and offers lots of various FB related functionality (all of which is optional).